# trouble installing rubygem

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

```
➜  ~  cloudapp Desktop/test.txt 


You need to install cloudapp_api: gem install cloudapp_api
➜  ~  sudo gem install cloudapp_api
Password:
Successfully installed cloudapp_api-0.3.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for cloudapp_api-0.3.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for cloudapp_api-0.3.1...


➜  ~  cloudapp ~/Desktop/test.txt  
You need to install cloudapp_api: gem install cloudapp_api


➜  ~  gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/bkern/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
➜  ~  
➜  ~  which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

  ~  ls -ls /usr/bin/ruby  
8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 Mar 23 10:16 /usr/bin/ruby -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby

➜  ~  ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

I am not sure how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated. I am running snow leopard.

> > Gem.all_load_paths.grep /cloudapp/
> >     NOTE: Gem.all_load_paths is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
> >     Gem.all_load_paths called from (irb):7.
> >     NOTE: Gem.all_partials is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
> >     Gem.all_partials called from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:260.
> >     NoMethodError: undefined method `specifications' for "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8":String
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:425:in`each_load_path'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:423:in `each'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:423:in`each_load_path'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:260:in `_deprecated_all_load_paths'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:259:in`each'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:259:in `_deprecated_all_load_paths'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:62:in`send'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:62:in `all_load_paths'
> >         from (irb):7

Comment: Ok..maybe there's something wrong with cloudapp_api and Rubygems 1.8.5. One more thing to try. In `irb` - what do these give you? `Gem.default_path`, and `Gem.all_load_paths.grep /cloudapp/`?

Answer (score 0):

The cloudapp binary is very simple..it begins like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
begin
  require 'cloudapp_api'
rescue LoadError
  puts "You need to install cloudapp_api: gem install cloudapp_api"
  exit!(1)
end
```

Here's what I would do:

1. "Make sure you have it plugged in fix": reinstall cloudapp (not the api, just the app).
2. In a clean irb (start with `irb -f`). Can you require cloudapp_api there (remember to require rubygems first)?
3. Check the bang-line (the first line) of the cloudapp binary (use `which cloudapp` to locate it). Is it running under the correct ruby binary?

These are the first steps of troubleshooting..let's see what you get..

Comment: having trouble posting the code from #2 it says LoadError: no such file to load ...for #3 it is #!/usr/bin/env ruby

Comment: That is weird..and what if you go into your gems directory `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems`, is the cloudapp_api folder there?

Comment: Btw. you can always edit your question to add more data or code to it. Adding code to comments doesn't work that well.

Comment: thanks for the tip I will edit hte question with the terminal output but I do see this gem in that folder.

Comment: still not working for me - not sure if anyone has suggestions otherwise I will update when I get through this

Comment: See my comment I added to your question..please check that.

Comment: >> Gem.default_path
=> ["/Users/bkern/.gem/ruby/1.8", "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8"]